# Python 3: Add function to class scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method `_prepare_engines` that I use in other methods of my class e.g. in the method `takeoff`:

```
    class Aircraft():
        def takeoff(self):
            self._prepare_engines() # prepare_engines happens
        def _prepare_engines(self):
            # some stuff
```

Since I have to use this method `_prepare_engines` a lot within my class methods I would like to have an abbreviation `a` for `self._prepare_engines` such that I can write my class methods like this (saving me the `self.` referencing):

```
    class Aircraft():
        def takeoff(self):
            a() # prepare_engines happens
        def _prepare_engines(self):
            # some stuff
```

Is there some way to add this abbreviation `a` to the scope of the class, such that

1. it does not pollute my global scope / can only be referenced from inside the class but not from outside the class
2. I do not have to define `a` like `a = self._prepare_engines`in every method in which I use it but only once in the class

Comment: You can't save the `self.` -- how is it supposed to know which instance should be used?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the requirement. You want to save yourself the time typing or something? An IDE or editor with intellisense should save you the typing and the headache of dealing with an otherwise very unusual pattern.

Comment: You can also just use `def a(self):`

Comment: Programming isn't about code golfing. The goal of writing code is to write readable, maintainable code, not to minimize the number of keystrokes. Remember: You only have to write the code once, but you (and others) will have to read it many times.

Comment: Actually, the main goal is readability. Writing ```self._a(...)``` or even nesting methods like ```self._a(self._b(...))``` in hundreds of lines of codes is really way less readable than ```a(...)``` or ```a(b(...)```

Comment: ```def a(self):``` does not solve the problem of readability (see comment above).